# display selection from sql select field in html

Tags: php, sql

I have created a form which includes a select field where users can select a date for a delivery, the code below pulls information from a sql table which stores the available delivery dates.
The problem i have is that im not sure how to display the selected date in a text box once they have made their selection (im sure this is simple code but my skills are basic!)

```
    <select id="test" name="test">
        <?php
        $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","id294054_mike_butcher","delivery1");
        $DB = mysql_select_db('id294054_delivery');
        $test = mysql_query("SELECT date FROM test WHERE selected is null");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($test)){
        echo '<option value="'. $row['value'] .'">'. $row['date'] .'</option>';
        }?>
    </select>
```

Comment: Where is this textbox in your code?

Comment: You would send the selection as a new request to the server and then select the wanted rows from db. When you base your query on user input, use mysqli or pdo with prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is working example


    <select id="test" name="test" onchange="updateInput(this.value)">
 <?php
        $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","id294054_mike_butcher","delivery1");
        $DB = mysql_select_db('id294054_delivery');
        $test = mysql_query("SELECT date FROM test WHERE selected is null");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($test)){
        echo '<option value="'. $row['value'] .'">'. $row['date'] .'</option>';
        }?></select>
    <input type="text" id="textInput" name="date" />

    <script>
    function updateInput(ish){
            console.log(ish);
        document.getElementById("textInput").value = ish;
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: thanks, this option works when i enter the individual options manually but not when pulling the data from my sql table

Comment: unfortunately, this still isn't printing the results from the query, the textbox is empty